# Resigning from tenure-track position after sabbatical for industry -- how little research can I do before I leave?

Tags: tenure-track, quitting, sabbatical

I'm on tenure-track and going to go on sabbatical in the fall for one semester. When I return from my sabbatical, I plan on giving a year's notice and switching to teaching part-time while I take over family business. Research is not for me, but I like and respect my colleagues and I want to do "right by them." My question is, how little research-related work can I do during my sabbatical and in the following year without jeopardizing my prospects for being hired as an adjunct afterwards and my relations with the department in general. I should mention that I am much liked as a teacher and coordinate a huge part of the undergraduate curriculum, so I trust that the department will want me to stick around...

Comment: Doing _right by them._ depends upon your own values and ethics.

Comment: How do sabbaticals work where you are?  Where I am, you have to have a proposal as to what you are going to do during the sabbatical.  Typically this includes research, but I don't know what you had proposed.  If you said you were going to do research, I think it would be unethical not to make a good-faith effort towards that.

Comment: I feel that for this question, internet academics who do not know you at all will not give as good an answer as friends or mentors within your university or department.  As @Nate Eldredge points out, expectations for what happens on the sabbatical can vary considerably from institution to institution, for one thing.  For another, the answer seems to depend crucially on the balance between research and teaching in your department...and even your own balance between research and teaching.  Since you're planning to quit no matter what, I advise you to ask these questions within your department.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why do you want to teach and run the family business when you could do just one?